# Intercepting Laravel job failing event to change log written

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I can catch the event with `\Queue::failing()` but how do I prevent the Laravel log from being written when a specific failure reason is detected?

For instance, when a job failed because it was attempted too many times, a `MaxAttemptsExceededException` is fired during failing. Suppose I wanted to interrupt that to add something to the log message or even change the log type to "warning" instead of "error". How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch exceptions by class within the [Exception Handler Class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#the-exception-handler).

Using the `report` method:

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof MaxAttemptsExceededException) {
        // add custom message
        // optionally return parent::report($exception); to continue normal flow
    }

    return parent::report($exception);
}
```